# Display emails of users who already posted at least once

Tags: author, email

I need to display on a page the list of emails of the users who already posted once on my site.

I have this snippet of code:

```
global $wpdb;
$min_posts = 1; 
$author_ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT `post_author` FROM
    (SELECT `post_author`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM {$wpdb->posts}
        WHERE `post_status`='publish' GROUP BY `post_author`) AS `stats`
    WHERE `count` >= {$min_posts} ORDER BY `count` DESC;");
```

But I have two issues: how can I choose to display it on a particular page (I usually add snippets to functions.php) and how can I get the emails instead of the iDs ?

I probably have to use `get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' )` but I don't know how to implement it here.

Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place following code in your functions.php file & use the shortcode `[myblogwriters min_posts="1"]` anywhere in the page/post content and can also change the min_posts value :)

```
function show_min_one_post_writers($atts){

    global $wpdb;

    $attrs = shortcode_atts( array(
            'min_posts' => ''
        ), $atts );

    $min_posts = $attrs['min_posts'];

    $authors = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT `post_author` FROM
    (SELECT `post_author`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM {$wpdb->posts}
    WHERE `post_status`='publish' GROUP BY `post_author`) AS `stats`
    WHERE `count` >= {$min_posts} ORDER BY `count` DESC;");

    $my_blog_writers = "";

    if ( empty ($authors) ) {
        return "<p>No one has contirbuted any post yet!</p>";
    } else {
        foreach ($authors as $author_id) {
            $my_writer = get_userdata($author_id);
            $my_blog_writers .= "<p>".$my_writer->first_name ." ".$my_writer->last_name ." : ". $my_writer->user_email."</p>";
        }
        return $my_blog_writers;
    }    
}
add_shortcode( 'myblogwriters', 'show_min_one_post_writers' );
```

Comment: Hi @itsMePN using shortcode is an good idea. so that they can place it anywhere they want easily without much programming. Thums up

Comment: @itsMePn amazing, very helpful. thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

If your query is correct and returns list of `user_id` then you can run the below

```
foreach($user_id_array as $user_id){
  echo get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $user_id );
  echo "<br>";//to print in new line for each user mail
}
```

You can use the above in page template or in any templating hook. For example you can print this in `wp_head`,`wp_footer` etc

Let us do this in an empty page. Let us assume the `page_id` is `8` then the following filter will do the trick

```
function print_selected_umail($content){

//check if we are in required page(8), so that we can add the selected user mail
if(is_page(8)){
    //queried result
        foreach($user_id_array as $user_id){
      $content .= get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $user_id );
      $content .= "<br>";//to print in new line for each user mail
    }
   }
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','print_selected_umail');
```